# скопировать файл на удаленный хост через scp

Tags: golang, scp

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как использовать scp(загрузить файл на удаленный сервер)? Есть некие ограничения, а именно, что у хоста нет доступа к интернету, только по локалке, на хосте есть только ssh и гарантированно есть scp, доставлять на хост больше ничего нельзя, подключение должно производиться по логину/паролю. Есть возможность это сделать на go(может какая митовская библиотека, мне найти неудалось)?

Answer (score 0):

если с Вашей машины ssh доступен, то нет никаких проблем.

```
scp ~/your_pc_file 192.168.0.100:/server/file.txt
```

то есть, вначале указывается локальный путь на Вашей машине, а потом, через пробел, имя машины, двоеточие и путь на удаленной машине (да, там тоже ~ работает).

Если удаленная машина прописана в ssh_config, то можно прям имя машины писать, имя пользователя и другие настройки автоматом применятся.

Если ssh_config не настроен, и ключи не скопированы, тогда возможно имя нужно задать ручками. Это не сложно

```
[user@]host:[path]
```

то есть

```
scp ~/your_pc_file vgp_framed@192.168.0.100:/server/file.txt
```

а пароль оно само спросит.

Comment: еще ограничение - подключение по логину/паролю

Comment: обновил ответ. Какие будут ещё ограничения?

Comment: теперь как это реализовать автоматически на golang? без постоянного ввода пароля в консоль...

Comment: зачем это делать на golang? просто что бы не вводить пароль? но тогда где то будете хранить пароль? просто скопируйте свои ключи на сервер и пароль спрашивать никто не будет.  гуглите ssh-copy-id

Comment: ключи использовать нельзя, в том то и дело.. пароль мне будет приходить в зашифрованном виде.. Это зоопарк хостов..

Comment: я понял, тот случай, когда легче уйти с компании. Но можете продолжить ковырять в этом направлении https://habr.com/ru/post/215111/ или научится просто запускать приложение и подсовывать ему пароль. Так наверно будет даже проще.

Comment: Я тоже об этом думаю) но пока не могу придумать - как)

Comment: вот для затравки https://gist.github.com/jedy/3357393
а потом перечитайте свой начальный вопрос и то, к чему мы пришли в конце.